# Rails - Rack how to TEST "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" by sending in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, utf-8, postman

I have been working on a middleware that encodes the body for UTF-8 and returns a 422 to the client if the string cannot be encoded. I have passing specs.

There are 99,234,3978,224 articles(I googled) on how to handle this but not how to test, and by test, I want to send invalid JSON to my local server via curl or postman.

I have tried a few things all `POST`'s

```
 { "name": "bad string \255" }
 { "name": "bad string \xAD" }
 { "name": "bad string <invaild japanese chars that some other post said was invaild>" }
```

Either ad chars where escaped the \ by adding another one or just treated it like text, which makes sense but not what I want.

Comment: Bad string is a JSON concept. Are you wanting to test bytes that are not valid UTF-8 or to test text that isn't valid JSON?

Comment: Looking to test bytes that are not valid UTF-8.

Comment: Then you can't send a text body; Send a byte sequence body. (Of course, you can still give it a JSON MIME type.)